# CSS - Div Won't Stay on Right Side of Other Div

Tags: css, css-float

Pretty simple set-up here, I'm just trying to get two divs to sit side-by-side. Image on the left, text on the right. For some reason, if the text is too long, it pushes the div down. I'd like to just make the cs-summary div understand that it should wrap the text in order to NOT jump down like it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/5Huau/

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cs-image">
        <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cs-summary">
        <p>Texty text text McTexterson likes to text. Why is div getting shoved down?</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="cs-image">
        <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cs-summary">
        <p>Super short text behaves.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.cs-image {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.cs-summary {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

As you can see from the second container below, the short text works just fine. I don't want to hardcode any pixel or em values for how wide the text is, I just want it to conform and "know" its bounds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `div.cs-summary` doesn't have a set `width` it will take up as much space as it can

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/5Huau/7/

```
.cs-summary {
    width: 180px;
    ...
}
```

---

or you could remove the wrapping inner div elements and just do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/5Huau/11/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />   
    <p>Texty text text McTexterson likes to text. Why is div getting shoved down?</p>        
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />
    <p>Super short text behaves.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container img {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.container p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: See, what's disturbing is, the .container p left margin is ignored. Why?

Comment: OK, odd.. if I give the p a margin-left of 18em, then it indents. It's like the p's left edge is underneath the img. Total confusion...

Comment: if you want that margin-left to work you'll need a set `width` and `display: inline-block;`: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/5Huau/12/

Comment: I think I will keep it simple and just remove your margin-left from the .container p and put a margin-right in .container img. That works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` from `.cs-summary`...

And probably use a `margin-right: 5px` or something on the `.cs-image` to get a space between them.

Comment: Removing the float:left from cs-summary makes its margin-left nonfunctional. But then I can put margin-right on the cs-image and that works. Not sure about this.. I thought to line up a bunch of divs left to right, they all had to be floated left?

Comment: CaptSaltyJack - Not necessarily. It depends on how you want the objects to interact. Check out this article on floats: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Comment: You could use the padding-left property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [not using floats at all](http://jsfiddle.net/5Huau/3/), or do you have to support versions of IE before 8?

```
.container {
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    width: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.cs-image {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.cs-summary {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Floats work just fine in IE7. In fact, oddly enough, my jsfiddle looks perfect in IE7 but not in Chrome. Weird.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack They don't, otherwise they'd look the same in IE7 as they did in Chrome.  But the point I was making was that it's better not to use floats at all, providing you don't have to support IE7.

Answer (score 0):

When floated left or right (as your example shows), DIV tags will auto expand to the content within them.  You can do two things to solve your problem:

1. Define a width on the div which contains your text
2. Instead of wrapping your text with a div tag and a paragraph tag (`<div><p>text here</p></div>`), remove the DIV from around the paragraph tag and add a `float:left` to the paragraph tag.  For example: `<p style="float:left;">text here</p>"`

Answer (score 0):

as hunter and user 671670 have pointed out, you have to use a width. Both elements must fit into the container in order to be displayed next to each other.
You could change your HTML and place the image inside the text and float it left, like this:

```
 <p>Texty text text McTexterson likes to text.
    Why is div getting shoved down?<img style="float:left" ... /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #0f0;
    width: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 400px;
}

.cs-image {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.cs-summary {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="cs-image">
        <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cs-summary">
        <p>Texty text text McTexterson likes to text. Why is div getting shoved down?</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="cs-image">
        <img src="http://www.electroniccampus.org/school_logos/CFNC/Wake_Forest_University/Wake_Forest_University2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cs-summary">
        <p>Super short text behaves.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just remove float right from cs-summary.